# JavaScript Reorders elements of an Object

Tags: javascript, object, key

Using JavaScript, I am trying to create the following object:

```
{name: "John Doe", grade: "3", 6: "six"}
```

Note that the key for the third element is a number, `6`.

I am creating the object as follows:

```
var myObject = {};

// Some code goes here

myObject["name"] = "John Doe";

// Some more code goes here

myObject["grade"] = "3";

// And even more code here

myObject["6"] = "six";
```

Now, the problem is the object gets constructed as follows

```
{6: "six", name: "John Doe", grade: "3"}
```

Note that the element `6: "six"` moved to the front of the object even though it was added last.

I noticed that all elements that have numbers as their keys get added to the front even though they get added after other elements. How I ensure that the elements are not re-arranged and keep my original order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simple answer is not possible.And this not a problem.Because object does not have sorting function.It's a default behaviour of the object.And also you calling the object values via key name, not the index.so sorting was not necessary

```js
var a ={6: "six", name: "John Doe", grade: "3"};

console.log(a['6']) // calling by keyname so position not a problem with that
```

**Updated**

If you need an order .use with array

```js
var myObject = [];

myObject.push({name : "John Doe"});
myObject.push({grade : "one"});
myObject.push({6 : "six"});

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: I understand the purpose of keys/values. But in our case, only in one situation, order IS important. Is there a way of ensuring that?

Comment: if you need a order you need to create Array inside object otherwise you  can't able to get the order

Comment: :(  ok, thanks for your help

Comment: @Greeso: *"Is there a way of ensuring that?"* No.

Comment: @Greeso see my updated answer

Comment: @prasad - Thanks for the suggestion, but was thinking of creating one additional array, an index array, that lists the order of the objects rather than making the object more complex.

Comment: @FelixKling - Thanks you

Comment: @Greeso For my suggestion, no need create the additional array.  you have to handle it an even more complex object in future .keep coding :)

Comment: @prasad - According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order#5525820  I could use `Map` instead of `Object`. I will try it.